# Question on quadratic equations .

Tags: number-theory, quadratics

A quadratic equation with roots $m$ and $n$ where $mn=4$ satisfies the equation $\frac {m}{m-1} + \frac {n}{n-1}=\frac {a^2 -7}{a^2 -4}$  . We have to find the number of integral values of $a$ for $m$, $n \in (1,4)$.

By comparing the given I found the quadratic equation as $x^2 -(a^2 +1)x +4 =0$.

But now after that I am stuck

Can anybody help me out how to proceed?

Source : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOpDl.gif

Comment: what is $x$ here?

Comment: If the roots are equal then $4 = (a^2 + 1)$.

Comment: but they must be not equal, we know only that $mn=4$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $(x-2)^2$ no ?

Comment: Check your calculations for the quadratic you got, I think it is wrong.

Comment: @A---B no it is correct

Comment: @Koolman Well then I think the question is wrong as I also got $\pm 2$ as the answer.

Comment: @A---B that also cannot the answer as using that we get one of the root as  4 which is not possible .

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner here x is a variable of a quadratic equation .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

The condition for the roots to lie within $(a,b)$ [i.e. $(1,4)$] should be used.

$f(a)>0$, $f(b)>0$, $x$ coordinate of vertex between $a$ and $b$ , $D \geq 0$ (discriminant)

Comment: @Angel Mario Gallegos. I think you should  un-delete your answer and add on the part in my comment to conclude there are no solutions, as the rest is fine.